# Deserialise serialized JSON into a Rust object?

Tags: json, rust

I'm a brand new Rust programmer. I have some text-serialized JSON. How can I take this input text and deserialize it into a Rust object?

All the `serde_json` examples I can find assume that you're starting with a standard JSON file, not a string of serialized JSON.

I know how to serialise a JSON file (called `my.json`) as follows:

```
let json_text = fs::read_to_string("my.json").expect("Unable to read file");
let json: serde_json::Value =
    serde_json::from_str(&json_text).expect("JSON was not well-formatted");
println!("{}", json);
```

I'd like to adapt this for a text file called `my.txt` containing the following text:

```
"{\"name\":\"as.up.data.forward\",\"time\":\"2023-03-13T18:58:41.933481750Z\"}"
```

In case it's relevant: I don't know the structure of the serialized JSON in advance.

Comment: @cafce25 I've edited - hopefully this is clearer?

Comment: Yes, now I get it, you encoded it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I get it now with the edit, you've encoded the data as JSON twice, so you have to decode it twice:

```rust
fn main() {
    // let j = &fs::read_to_string("my.json").expect("Unable to read file");
    let j = r#""{\"name\":\"as.up.data.forward\",\"time\":\"2023-03-13T18:58:41.933481750Z\"}""#;

    let v: String = serde_json::from_str(j).expect("not a string");
    dbg!(&v);

    let vv: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&v).unwrap();
    dbg!(vv);
}
```

Comment: Why are you deserializing to `serde_json::Value`? At least in the first time, deserialize directly to `String`.